# regular expression to met length firstly then check other pattern?

Tags: python, python-re, regular-language

I don't know how to express the question in English title exactly, there are 2 rules

1. firstly, met the given length as long as possible on the head and end part
2. then match the other pattern

for example,

1. must read 2~3 chars before number and must read 2~4 chars after the number if the string is long enough; if the string is not long enough, read only possible
2. check whether the char before number is not `a`, and the char after number is not `z`

--- edit on 20220620 ----
the code is what exactly the following table tried to express

```
import re
lst = {
'abc123defg':'abc123defg',
'babc123defg':'abc123defg',
'aba123defg':'""',
'abc123zefg':'""',
'bc123def':'bc123def',
'c123def':'c123def',
'c123zef':'""',
'c123d':'c123d'
}

reStr = r".{1,2}[^a\d]\d+[^z\d].{1,3}"
reStr = r"^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[B-Zb-z]\d+[A-Ya-y][A-Za-z]{1,3}"

for key, value in lst.items():
    match = re.match(reStr, key, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
    if match:
        print(f'{key:15s} expected to be: {value:15s}, really get: {match.group():15s}')
    else:
        print(f'{key:15s} expected to be: {value:15s}, really get: ""')
```

--- the following description is the old one which I did not edit it now

| text | expected find | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123defg | abc123defg | first read in 'abc123defg', in which `c` does not break `[^a]`, and `d` does not break `[^z]`. so 'abc123defg' is matched |
| babc123defg | abc123defg | first read in 'abc123defg', in which `c` does not break `[^a]`, and `d` does not break `[^z]`. so 'abc123defg' is matched |
| aba123defg | nothing | first read in 'abc123defg', in which `a` breaks `[^a]`, and `d` does not break `[^z]`. so `''` is matched |
| abc123zefg | nothing | first read in 'abc123defg', in which `c` does not break `[^a]`, but `z` does break `[^z]`. so `''` is matched |
| bc123def | bc123def | first read in 'bc123def', in which `c` does not break `[^a]`, and `d` does not break `[^z]`. so 'bc123def' is matched |
| c123def | c123def | first read in 'c123def', in which `c` does not break `[^a]`, and `d` does not break `[^z]`. so 'c123def' is matched |
| c123zef | nothing | first read in 'c123def', in which `c` does not break `[^a]`, and `z` does break `[^z]`. so '' is matched |
| c123d | c123d | first read in 'c123d', in which `c` does not break `[^a]`, and `d` does not break `[^z]`. so 'c123d' is matched |

so I write the regular expression in Python

```py
import re
lst = ['abc123defg', 'aba123defg', 'abc123zefg', 'bc123def']

for text in lst:
    print(text, ' -> ', re.match(r".{1,2}[^a]\d*[^z].{1,3}", text, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE).group())
```

but, of cause, the answer is not expected

```
abc123defg  ->  abc123defg
aba123defg  ->  aba123
abc123zefg  ->  abc123zef
bc123def  ->  bc123def
```

So is there a way to meet the expectation with just regular expression? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I changed the regexp to:

```
r".{1,2}[^a\d]\d+[^z\d].{1,3}"
```

The point is to match the number correctly:

- at least one digit: `\d+` instead of `\d*`
- in order to exactly know what is before and after the number, you need to match the number only by the above mentioned `\d+`. That's why I "added" `[^\d]` before and after.

Comment: no, this RE can only extract treat the string I wrote in python code, however, not all the cases I listed in the table, or `lst = ['abc123defg', 'babc123defg', 'aba123defg', 'abc123zefg', 'bc123def', 'c123def', 'c123zef', 'c123d']`

Comment: You are right, it is not a complete solution written for you. It only covers the case *"must read 2~3 chars before number ..."*. My answer shows where your RE had a mistake. Should be easy to finish it. Sorry for not stating that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 rules can be encompassed in a single regex pattern. Try with this expression:

```
regex = re.compile("^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[B-Zb-z]\d+[A-Ya-y][A-Za-z]{1,3}")
```

Simple and self-explanatory:

- Find 1 to 2 alphabetic characters
- Find one more alphabetic character, excluding chars A | a
- Continue with any digits sequence
- After that, find another alphabetic character, excluding chars Z | z
- Find 1 to 3 more alphabetic characters

Then you will be able to reproduce your code with the expected results.

A `try` clause will be needed in order to avoid None related AttributeErrors, for the cases where the pattern is not matched:

```
for text in lst:
try:
    print(text, ' -> ', re.match("^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[B-Zb-z]\d+[A-Ya-y][A-Za-z]{1,3}", text).group())
except AttributeError:
    print(text, ' -> No pattern found')
```

Comment: Looks like a good case for `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: no, this RE can only extract treat the string I wrote in python code, however, not all the cases I listed in the table, or `lst = ['abc123defg', 'babc123defg', 'aba123defg', 'abc123zefg', 'bc123def', 'c123def', 'c123zef', 'c123d']`

Comment: Well, there are certain cases in your list that does not meet your rules criteria: "must read 2~3 chars before number and must read 2~4 chars after the number if the string is long enough; if the string is not long enough, read only possible":


"c123def", "c123d", "babc123defg"... sould not be selected if we follow these rules.